# Amazon S3 upload using rest API and node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, parse-platform

guys, I want to upload image to S3 storage, but I can't do it.

My app is on parse.com and I can't use npm to install aws-sdk

Please, help me, I'm newbie in aws and node.js.

Comment: https://parse.com/questions/solutions-to-upload-to-s3-through-cloud-code

Answer (score 1):

I posted a link as a comment, however I will give it a bit of explanation.

I am not sure if it is possible to upload to S3 through Parse (mainly because that would be alot of unnecessary traffic for Parse), however it is possible to upload to S3 directly from your client by using a certificate. This (signed) certificate effectively tells S3 that you are authorizing the device to upload to your bucket as long as the requirements included in the certificate are met.

[This question](https://parse.com/questions/solutions-to-upload-to-s3-through-cloud-code) on Parse's site give more information about this, as well as Cloud Code that should generate the certificate for you. As always, I would recommend you understand what this code is doing before you use it for any production app/service.

You can also probably find some more information about this client-side upload by doing a quick google for something like 'client side upload to S3'.

Comment: I'm uploading image to parse, making some works (like resize and etc) and want to upload after them.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a perfect place to use https://www.inkfilepicker.com

Just plug in your own S3 creeds and off you go.

If you can't stand not doing something painful use the REST API here for S3 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3_Authentication2.html and build out your cloud code functions with the networking capability available in parse

There is a reason inkfilepicker exists tho...

Comment: 5000 files - about 1200 users for 100$ a month. Too much for free app.

Comment: The first 5k are free. It would take 20000 files more to ever cost you $100. $.005 per file is a almost as good a price as it will be when u go over your parse 1M calls (7¢ per thousand) trying to build your own form actions.

Comment: If you wanted to pay per gb https://transloadit.com/docs#jquery-plugin